# find equation of tangent line to y=1/x^2 at point where x=-1

Tags: calculus, derivatives

find equation of tangent line to y=1/x^2 at point where x=-1

I got the right answer by finding f'(-1)=2
and plugged (-1,1) and 2 as slope to get y-1=2(x+1)

I know there's more complicated way of solving but just want to be sure if the way I did it is correct.

This question does not meet our quality standard? I'm new to this and have no idea what this means.... please its easy question but our teacher didn't teach this specifically and I have a calculus test today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are absolutely right.